# BigQuery Job Concurrent Policy Changes Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I got the following error message while running a BigQuery interactive job which reads and writes data:

```
Error: IAM setPolicy failed for Dataset ${PROJECT_ID}:_script3642538fdc8a1752fde19ea33f2a0c66ff906a1d:
There were concurrent policy changes. Please retry the whole read-modify-write with exponential backoff.
```

I am struggling to understand why would IAM setPolicy fail on a temporary dataset with a concurrency error?

Comment: This is caused by  conflicting IAM policy changes that occur concurrently; for example,  an IAM policy update (ex. adding views) is still being processed when an IAM policy deletion (ex. user group) occurs. Taking a look at  official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#access_revoke), IAM propagation may take anywhere between 60 seconds and 7 minutes for these changes to fully propagate across the system. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Each BigQuery job is doing some aggregations and recreating a corresponding view in the dataset via `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` DDL statement. Multiple jobs are running at the same time, but each one is recreating a different view in the dataset.

Could you give me an example, what else has to happen during the view recreation, that I experience this error? How could I try to reproduce it? It only happened once out of hundreds of job executions.

Comment: How many jobs are you running? Please check official doc about [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs)